# click function does not working with ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If i use like following,I got what i need.. Here is the code.

```
<style>
  .moreMenu {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        z-index: 10;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #666;
        border-radius: 0 0 0 4px;
        background: #FFF;
        display: none;
        border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    }
</style>
 <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v tbButton otherOptions rightSide"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <div class="moreMenu">
          heloo
   </div>
<script>
  $(".otherOptions").click(function () {

                $(".moreMenu").slideToggle("fast");
            });
</script>
```

But if i use ng-if condition,

```
 <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v tbButton otherOptions rightSide"  aria-hidden="true" ng-if="member==''"></i>
```

click function is not working.

Comment: nowhere in your code you are using `ng-click`. `$().click()` has different functionalities

Comment: Are you implement your application with angularjs? If yes, then why are you using jquery click function()?

Comment: click function is not working only when  i include <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v tbButton otherOptions rightSide"  aria-hidden="true" ng-if="member==''">    ng-if condition

Comment: without if condition, it is working

Comment: @athi try swapping `ng-if` with `ng-show`. Also [avoid using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/8495123)

Comment: did you got any console error?

Comment: no.. jquery and angular js issues... thanks for the hint.. :) thanks @AlekseySolovey, Ramesh Rajendran

Comment: @athi please check with my answer if you want use jquery event in angularjs

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue..

```
<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v tbButton otherOptions rightSide"  aria-hidden="true" ng-if=members==''" ng-click="mymore()"></i>


// controller
     $scope.mymore = function(){    
        $(".moreMenu").slideToggle("fast");
    }
```

Thanks all for the informations...

Comment: But appreciate your works. But do you know why the click does not working if you are using `ng-if`?

Comment: @RameshRajendran my guess it that unlike `ng-show`, `ng-if` doesn't hide the content but [removes DOM entirely](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf#overview). Since jQuery isn't part of AngularJS's digest cycle, the div with `moreMenu` class is not rendered yet for `$(...)` to grab it

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use `ng-click` but if you need to use jQuery's click event, you can add a filtered click event to the body:

```
$('body').on('click', '.otherOptions', function() {
  $('.moreMenu').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

this will add an event handler on the body but will only trigger if the event bubbles up from the `otherOptions` element. This is an approach to handling dynamic content with jQuery events

Answer (score 0):

@athi is your answer is a proper answer. But as per the question I have answered here use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`.

```js
angular.module("a",[]).controller("ac",function($scope){
   

    });
```

```css
.otherOptions
{
color: #666;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="a" ng-controller="ac">
 <input class="otherOptions" type="button" value="hello" ng-click="mymore()" ng-show=true>
    <div class="moreMenu">
          heloodfg
   </div>
   </div>
 <script>
 $(".otherOptions").click(function () {
        $(".moreMenu").slideToggle("fast");
    });
 </script>
```